# How to include static asset/image with svelte component and webpack?

Tags: webpack, svelte, webpack-file-loader, svelte-component

I want to create a svelte component (based on webpack) which uses/imports a static image. 
How do I make sure that the image gets properly exported, i.e. that a svelte app using my component also sees the image?

In my component, I tried importing the image and using the file-loader for webpack:

```
import image from "./image.jpg";
```

and

```
{
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [
        'file-loader',
    ],
}
```

This works, the image is included in the dist folder, but in this case I also need to add a file-loader to the main svelte app, which is an additional requirement I want to avoid. The main app should only need to import my component.

Is this possible or is the above already the recommended approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is an [open issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-loader/issues/114) of svelte-loader.